# Json parsing fails out of the blue

Tags: json

So I've been struggling with JSON for awhile now, however last night something weird happened, even tho I have " escaped it brings up an error, here's my JSON string

```
var data = $.parseJSON('{"rows":[{"type":"row","width_class":"row new_row","column_class":"col3 column_model","columns":{"0":{"class":"column one","children":[]},"1":{"class":"column one","children":[{"type":"bullet-block","html":"<div class=\\"bullet-block-element\\"><ul><li style='padding-left:36px;background-image:url(\\"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png\\");'>123</li><li style='padding-left:36px;background-image:url(\\"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png\\");'>456</li><li style='padding-left:36px;background-image:url(\\"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png\\");'>789</li></ul></div>","image":"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png","size":"large","items":["123","456","789"]}]},"2":{"class":"column one","children":[]}}}]}');
```

This is generated via

```
var data = $.parseJSON('<?= str_replace('\\','\\\\',base64_decode($data['d'])) ?>');
```

Am I just being blind or have I had too much redbull? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode` does the escaping and it will automatically be exposed as JSON, you don't need `$.parseJSON`, it's double decoding there.

Simply use this:

```
<?php
$php = array('test' => 'hi');

$data['d'] = base64_encode(json_encode($php)); // 'eyJ0ZXN0IjoiaGkifQ=='

?>


<script>

var data = <?php echo base64_decode($data['d']); ?>;
console.debug(data.test); // Prints 'hi' in the console ;-)

</script>
```

See the codepad: http://codepad.org/VmKGt0JD

Comment: that will assign JSON string to the data variable, however I need data to actually be the json object?

Comment: Note: There are no quotes arround the PHP, it won't be a string, it is actual data.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the `'`'s as well (styles in the html tags)

so this will work

`var data = $.parseJSON('{"rows":[{"type":"row","width_class":"row new_row","column_class":"col3 column_model","columns":{"0":{"class":"column one","children":[]},"1":{"class":"column one","children":[{"type":"bullet-block","html":"<div class=\\"bullet-block-element\\"><ul><li style=\'padding-left:36px;background-image:url(\\"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png\\");\'>123</li><li style=\'padding-left:36px;background-image:url(\\"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png\\");\'>456</li><li style=\'padding-left:36px;background-image:url(\\"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png\\");\'>789</li></ul></div>","image":"http://example.com/includes/images/bulletins/large-0.png","size":"large","items":["123","456","789"]}]},"2":{"class":"column one","children":[]}}}]}');`

copied and pasted to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w99L7tp/)

Comment: Howcome JSON.stringify doesn't do this?

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius I haven't ever looked into it, [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) if your interested. I usually manually escape everything (there are built in functions in most server side languages for this)